# How to connect J2me application through java(port)?

Tags: java, java-me

I have created j2me application in port 50000. I want to connect that j2me application from java? Can anybody suggest me?

Answer (score 2):

You can run java application on web server and access that application from J2ME classes through HTTP protocol. You can also use Java socket to communicate with server. But in both approaches, you need to initiate the connection from J2ME application as server will not have IP address of device. If you need to invoke/start J2ME application from remote Java application then you can use Push Registry. You can find more information in this article: [The MIDP 2.0 Push Registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/)